# Parallel nested for loop in Python

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, trigonometry

I am trying to use resources online to parallelize my nested for loop but can't seem to understand how it properly works.

This is my original function (which computes a cosine similarity between every combination of two strings stored in a list)

```
def compute_similarity(list):

  for i in range(len(list)):
      for j in range(len(list)):
    
        if i == j:
          pass
    
        else: 
          similarity = get_sim(list[i], list[j])
          sim_df.iloc[i,j] = similarity
```

I tried with the multiprocessing library, but without any luck. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: As an aside, `im_df.iloc[i,j] = similarity` is incredibly slow. Use `im_df.iat[i, j] = similarity`

Comment: Approximately how long is `list` ?

Comment: You can halve the number of calls to `get_sim`  by using `for j in range(i+1, len(list))` and setting both `[i,j]` and `[j,i]` in each iteration

Comment: What does ‘ without any luck. ’ mean? Be specific: an error, no improvement, what?

Comment: This is not a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) using realistic data against which someone could actually test a solution to see whether a multiprocessing solution improves performance. You need to update your question.

Answer (score 1):

(Probably off topic)

```py
l = [38, 12, 44, 24, 43, 3, 19, 31, 47, 31]
m = np.ones((len(l), len(l))) * l
```

```
>>> m
array([[38., 12., 44., 24., 43.,  3., 19., 31., 47., 31.],
       [38., 12., 44., 24., 43.,  3., 19., 31., 47., 31.],
       [38., 12., 44., 24., 43.,  3., 19., 31., 47., 31.],
       [38., 12., 44., 24., 43.,  3., 19., 31., 47., 31.],
       [38., 12., 44., 24., 43.,  3., 19., 31., 47., 31.],
       [38., 12., 44., 24., 43.,  3., 19., 31., 47., 31.],
       [38., 12., 44., 24., 43.,  3., 19., 31., 47., 31.],
       [38., 12., 44., 24., 43.,  3., 19., 31., 47., 31.],
       [38., 12., 44., 24., 43.,  3., 19., 31., 47., 31.],
       [38., 12., 44., 24., 43.,  3., 19., 31., 47., 31.]])
```

Apply [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity):

```py
num = m.T.dot(m)
norm = (m ** 2).sum(axis=0) ** 0.5
```

```py
>>> num / (norm * norm.T)
array([[ 1.        ,  3.16666667,  0.86363636,  1.58333333,  0.88372093,
        12.66666667,  2.        ,  1.22580645,  0.80851064,  1.22580645],
       [ 0.31578947,  1.        ,  0.27272727,  0.5       ,  0.27906977,
         4.        ,  0.63157895,  0.38709677,  0.25531915,  0.38709677],
       [ 1.15789474,  3.66666667,  1.        ,  1.83333333,  1.02325581,
        14.66666667,  2.31578947,  1.41935484,  0.93617021,  1.41935484],
       [ 0.63157895,  2.        ,  0.54545455,  1.        ,  0.55813953,
         8.        ,  1.26315789,  0.77419355,  0.5106383 ,  0.77419355],
       [ 1.13157895,  3.58333333,  0.97727273,  1.79166667,  1.        ,
        14.33333333,  2.26315789,  1.38709677,  0.91489362,  1.38709677],
       [ 0.07894737,  0.25      ,  0.06818182,  0.125     ,  0.06976744,
         1.        ,  0.15789474,  0.09677419,  0.06382979,  0.09677419],
       [ 0.5       ,  1.58333333,  0.43181818,  0.79166667,  0.44186047,
         6.33333333,  1.        ,  0.61290323,  0.40425532,  0.61290323],
       [ 0.81578947,  2.58333333,  0.70454545,  1.29166667,  0.72093023,
        10.33333333,  1.63157895,  1.        ,  0.65957447,  1.        ],
       [ 1.23684211,  3.91666667,  1.06818182,  1.95833333,  1.09302326,
        15.66666667,  2.47368421,  1.51612903,  1.        ,  1.51612903],
       [ 0.81578947,  2.58333333,  0.70454545,  1.29166667,  0.72093023,
        10.33333333,  1.63157895,  1.        ,  0.65957447,  1.        ]])

>>> pd.DataFrame(num / (norm * norm.T), index=l, columns=l).round(2)
      38    12    44    24    43     3     19    31    47    31
38  1.00  3.17  0.86  1.58  0.88  12.67  2.00  1.23  0.81  1.23
12  0.32  1.00  0.27  0.50  0.28   4.00  0.63  0.39  0.26  0.39
44  1.16  3.67  1.00  1.83  1.02  14.67  2.32  1.42  0.94  1.42
24  0.63  2.00  0.55  1.00  0.56   8.00  1.26  0.77  0.51  0.77
43  1.13  3.58  0.98  1.79  1.00  14.33  2.26  1.39  0.91  1.39
3   0.08  0.25  0.07  0.12  0.07   1.00  0.16  0.10  0.06  0.10
19  0.50  1.58  0.43  0.79  0.44   6.33  1.00  0.61  0.40  0.61
31  0.82  2.58  0.70  1.29  0.72  10.33  1.63  1.00  0.66  1.00
47  1.24  3.92  1.07  1.96  1.09  15.67  2.47  1.52  1.00  1.52
31  0.82  2.58  0.70  1.29  0.72  10.33  1.63  1.00  0.66  1.00
```

Comment: I think I'm off topic and I'm sorry for that but this code should probably be run faster than nested loops. Therefore, maybe you don't have to use multiprocessing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm trying to follow but I'm slightly confused about the denom/norm/norm.T piece. I'm not fully understanding how it's scaling to compute on each combination.

Comment: Numpy uses vectorized functions and delegates their execution to highly optimized and parallel C/Fortran functions. Looping in Python can be slow and multiprocessing add overhead, NumPy vectorized functions could be the best compromise.

Answer (score 0):

in python, to get a basic parallel processing going is relatively easy. You can put the function into a class that inherits from `Thread` and just spin new threads for each piece of computation.

```py
class SentenceThread(Thread):
    def __init__(
        self,
        sentence: string,
    ):
        super().__init__()
        self.sentence = sentence


    def run(self) -> None:
        #do your thing with cosine calculation
        pass


sentence_threads = []

for sentence in sentences:
    sentence_thread = SentenceThread(sentence)
    sentence_thread.start()
    sentence_threads.append(sentence_thread)

for sentence_thread in sentence_threads:
    sentence_thread.join()
```

When you call `start` on an instance, then the `run` function will be called in a new thread. So you need to put your computation heavy function there.

For further reference, take a look at [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html).

Comment: Of course, in CPython, this won't actually run in parallel.